# redirect desktop to mobile error

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I created a webpage www.m.burdichiro.com/indexM.html where I tried to redirect mobile users to it from my original site, www.burdichiro.com using .htaccess file. It will not open, and comes up with an error that site is not available, and shows www.newdomain.com in the address window. I can open open burdichiro.com/index.html but this shows my desktop view, which is too large for my mobile screen. That is why I created indexM.html but it will not go there. Any suggestions?
Here is the coding in htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
# Check for mime types commonly accepted by mobile devices
RewriteCond %{HTTP_ACCEPT} *text\/vnd\.wap\.wml|application\/vnd\.wap\.xhtml\+xml" [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$
RewriteRule ^ http://www.m.burdichiro.com/indexM.html%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

Comment: Setting up two different “versions” of a website is not usually how this is done any more these days … you should rather look into responsive layout techniques/CSS media queries. _“and shows www.newdomain.com in the address window”_ – nothing in your code as shown suggest why it should change to a completely different domain. And have you first of all checked if your mobile device actually sends such an `accept` header in the first place …?

Comment: I am too inexperienced to check much. Just know that I copied code from a suggestion and it did not work. Tried many ones and each failed. Went back to script coding and that works so I guess htaccess is too hard for me. Thanks for your thoughts.